# html pattern: should not accept only spaces or only new-line characters or tabs or only carriage return

Tags: regex, html, textarea

I am adding HTML5 form validations for textarea

Textarea should accept valid string.

It should not accept

- only spaces
- only newline characters
- only tabs
- only carriage return
- only new line characters.

`<textarea maxlength="180" required="true" rows="5" name="description" pattern=".."></textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all the white space characters with `""` and if the string ends up being empty, return false

```
function checkValid(yourstring) {
   return (yourstring.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, "") != "");
};
```

Comment: Thanks for response @devnull69.. but I would like to have it in patter with regex, don't want to add extra jq code for it.. It would be great if you can help me with regex.

Comment: ... maybe I didn't get it correctly ... you mean something like `\t\n` would be correct?

Comment: in html5 textrea if we add required, it also accepts spaces and new-lines.. which is invalid.. so want to avoid it with pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?![^\s]+$).*$
```

Try this.This will not accept only 
    only spaces
    only newline characters
    only tabs
    only carriage return
    only new line characters.

Comment: Thanks @vks but just now I found that html5 textarea does not support pattern.. sorry :(

Comment: @Swati which pattern ?

Comment: check code snippet in above question.. there is attribute pattern in html tag